# Excel Drop down filter - How do I add a option to unselect filter and display all data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist, excel-filter

Don't know the exact wording, so apologises if title seems confusing.

In short I'm doing up a small data input table for my local swimming club whereby they can enter in the raw data of the competing swimmers including: Name, Gender, Age, Stroke Type, Distance & their time.

I've followed a simple tutorial that has allowed me to create dynamic lists which I've then turned into dependent drop down lists so they may filter through the data with.

My problem is if a particular swimmer has swam in multiple events of various distances currently I can only select on the filter that 1 stroke type & 1 distance, instead what I want to do is be able to add an option e.g. "All" that when selected it will disable that specifc filter (until I make a selection) and display all the strokes / distances that particular swimmer has competed in.

For example:

Swimmer James has swam in Backstroke 200 Metres & Backstroke 100 Metres.
I currently can select under distance 100 Metres or 200 Metres but I can't select both.
Instead I want to be able to not only view the individual distances but I also want to view all the distances.

Current formula for filtering is as follows:

```
=FILTER(SwimData,(SwimData[Name]=I3)*(SwimData[Gender]=J3)*(SwimData[Age]=K3)*(SwimData[Stroke]=L3)*(SwimData[Distance]=M3),"")
```

Comment: convert each criteria to an `if` statement for example: `(SwimData[Name]=I3)` becomes `IF(C6<>"All",SwimData[Name]=C6,ISTEXT(SwimData[Name])=TRUE)`. When numbers are involved use `ISNUMBER`. Depending this may fail with blank data.

Comment: This has given me the same result as the formula I posted in my main post.
I think its my fault as I didn't explain about the dependant dropdown lists & how its set up.

End users will input the raw data into the table and then in a separate worksheet I'm using a dynamic list with the following formula `=SORT(UNIQUE(SwimData[Name]))` I then use the following source: `='Data Lists'!$A$3#` for the dropdown list's menu.

What I want to do is be able to add an All option to that list that won't be removed when data is entered and when select this All option will show all data within it 1-2

Comment: So for example you want to see everyone that has done the stroke "Backstroke" for 200 Metres distance. So you would set the Stroke filter to "Backstroke" & the "Distance filter to "200 Metres" meanwhile the Name filter will be set to "All" so that it displays all the swimmer names that participated in that event. 2-2

Comment: I think you'll now need to upgrade your dynamic filter with `VSTACK()` to add `All` to the various lists